# Google Drive Android SDK: where to start from?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have been looking all day at the Google Drive SDK for Android,

but I am a bit confused.

I need to make the list of folders and files in the user Google Drive account.

I thought that was a simple, basic standard feature, but maybe not...

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possible ways to go:

- use [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), or
- use [Google Drive Android Api (GDAA)](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

I would say the former would be easier to start with.

- If you decide to go with the REST, you may use the [GitHub demo here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo), that has both the REST and the GDAA 'CRUD' implementations (you just comment out the one you don't need). It also has some code to deal with the authentication / authorization which you need to do anything on Google Drive. See [SO 28439129](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439129/how-to-acknowledge-when-user-doesnt-want-to-connect-to-google-play-services).
- In case you decide to use GDAA, (you still have to get the authorization done), the 'official' to get you started demos are [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) and [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos).

You will definitely run into a lot of roadblocks and the solutions are mostly found here under the tag ['google-drive-android-api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-android-api).

Good Luck.

Comment: ... and RESTful API has this great playground (bottom of this page https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list ) that is essential if you want to play or test anything related to Google Drive API.