# Uploading text messages to google drive from android not working

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

First time I am using GoogleApiClient and want to upload all the text messages to google drive when the share button in the app is clicked. But the data is not uploading on the drive.

MainActivity :

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


            RecyclerView rv;
            SmsAdapter adapter;
            FloatingActionButton fab;
            Cursor c;
            ExportTask task;
            ArrayList<CustomSms> smslistSearch;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                smslistSearch = new ArrayList<>();
                rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messages_view);

                LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                rv.setLayoutManager(llm);


                fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,SendSms.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });



            }

            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();


                try {


                    final ArrayList<CustomSms> smslist, smsgrouplist;

                    smslist = new ArrayList<>();
                    smsgrouplist = new ArrayList<>();

                    //Fetch inobx sms message
                    c = getContentResolver().query(SmsApplication.INBOX_URI, null, null, null, null);


                    while (c.moveToNext()) {
                        String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
                        String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
                        String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));

                        smslist.add(new CustomSms(address, date, body));
                    }



                    smslistSearch = smslist;
                    Map<String, CustomSms> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

                    for (CustomSms ays : smslist) {

                        CustomSms existingValue = map.get(ays.address);
                        if(existingValue == null){
                            map.put(ays.address, ays);
                        }
                    }

                    smsgrouplist.clear();
                    smsgrouplist.addAll(map.values());


                    adapter = new SmsAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                    adapter.updateList(smsgrouplist);
                    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

                    rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
                            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                    // TODO Handle item click
                                    ArrayList<CustomSms> smsinsidegroup = new ArrayList<CustomSms>();

                                    String n = smsgrouplist.get(position).address;

                                    for (int i = 0; i < smslist.size(); i++) {
                                        if(smslist.get(i).address.equals(n))
                                           smsinsidegroup.add(smslist.get(i));
                                    }

                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReadAllSms.class);
                                    i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("messages", smsinsidegroup);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            })
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            class ExportTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Uri> {

            ProgressDialog pDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Exporting to file ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgress(0);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Uri doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    try {
                        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SmsBackUp.txt");
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        int count = c.getCount(), i = 0;

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                sb.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")))
                                        .append("\n");
                                sb.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body")))
                                        .append("\n");
                                sb.append("\n");
                                publishProgress(++i*100/count);
                            } while (!isCancelled() && c.moveToNext());
                        }
                        fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                        return Uri.fromFile(f);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    } finally {
                        if (fos != null) {
                            try {
                                fos.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {}
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                pDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Uri result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                pDialog.dismiss();

                if (result == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Export task failed!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UploadData.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                if (id == R.id.action_search) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
                    i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("search", smslistSearch);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
                if (id == R.id.action_share) {
                    /*Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UploadData.class);
                    startActivity(i);*/

                    task = new ExportTask();
                    task.execute();
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                if (task != null) {
                    task.cancel(false);
                    task.pDialog.dismiss();
                }
                super.onPause();
            }

        }
```

UploadData :

```
        public class UploadData extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


            private static final String TAG = "upload_file";
            private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
            private File textFile;
            private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
            public static String drive_id;
            public static DriveId driveID;

            FrameLayout rl;
            TextView success;
            ProgressBar progressBar;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_data);


                rl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
                success = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.success);
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

                View root = rl.getRootView();
                root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackOrig));

                textFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SmsBackUp.txt");

                buildGoogleApiClient();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                Log.i(TAG, "connecting...");
                googleApiClient.connect();
            }

            protected void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                if (googleApiClient != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "disConnecting...");
                    googleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                            Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "In onActivityResult() - connecting...");
                    googleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                Log.i(TAG, "in onConnected() -  connected");
                Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(googleApiClient)
                        .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                switch (cause) {
                    case 1:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended - Cause: " + "Service disconnected");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended - Cause: " + "Connection lost");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended - Cause: " + "Unknown");
                        break;
                }
            }

            final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
                    ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Error creating the new file of contents");
                                return;
                            }
                            final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
                            new Thread() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                                    addTextfileToOutputStream(outputStream);
                                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                            .setTitle("SmsBackup")
                                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                            .setDescription("This is a text file uploaded from device")
                                            .setStarred(true).build();
                                    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(googleApiClient)
                                            .createFile(googleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                            .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    };

            private void addTextfileToOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                try {
                    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                            new FileInputStream(textFile));
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
                    ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                Toast.makeText(UploadData.this,
                                        "Error adding file to Drive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(UploadData.this,
                                    "File successfully added to Drive", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            showProgress(false);

                            rl.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBack));
                            View root = rl.getRootView();
                            root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBack));

                            success.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            final PendingResult<DriveResource.MetadataResult> metadata
                                    = result.getDriveFile().getMetadata(googleApiClient);
                            metadata.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveResource.MetadataResult>() {
                                                                   @Override
                                                                   public void onResult(DriveResource.MetadataResult metadataResult) {
                                                                       Metadata data = metadataResult.getMetadata();
                                                                       drive_id = data.getDriveId().encodeToString();
                                                                       driveID = data.getDriveId();

                                                                   }
                                                               });
                        }
                    };

            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                }
            }

            private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
                if (googleApiClient == null) {
                    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                            .addApi(Drive.API)
                            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .build();
                }
            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
            private void showProgress(final boolean show) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                    int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

                    progressBar.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    progressBar.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                            show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check on how you [work with File Contents](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files#making_modifications), first you might want to check if there is a value on the variable `textFile` that you have set.

The example below illustrates how to append "hello world" to the DriveContents.

```
try {
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = contents.getParcelFileDescriptor();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor
.getFileDescriptor());
// Read to the end of the file.
fileInputStream.read(new byte[fileInputStream.available()]);

// Append to the file.
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor
.getFileDescriptor());
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
writer.write("hello world");
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is a related SO question - [Upload text file to Google Drive using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108782/5995040) that you might want to check out. The answer in the question reminds the OP regarding how to feed the file with contents.

Lastly, you might want to check this [github](https://github.com/yelsane/sept_tries_fb/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sept/tries/firebase/activities/ChatRoomActivity.java). This code show how to insert the content of the chat into a file and save it to the drive.

Hope this helps.