# Backup and Restore Sqlite database to google drive

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-drive-api

I have read some articles  to backup and restore the sqlite db in xamarin forms to google drive with the help of google developer account and i have to use api key for that.
I am not able to understand that  if i deploy my app to the playstore and if the user want to use his email id then how it will be possible to backup the database to his google drive account without an api key.
I have read lots of articles but not able to understand .I request any expert has done same thing then kinldy share me some article for same.

Comment: You should implement support for OAuth2.0 in your app: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth

Comment: if a user want to use his own mail id then how it would be possible ?

Comment: There should be a lot of links to this, you could try to look at this:There should be a lot of links to this, you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853316/using-google-drive-to-backup-and-restore-sqlite-database